# Python gettext - not translating

Tags: python, internationalization, gettext

Sample python program: [CGI script, so it needs to select its own language rather than using whatever the host OS is set to]

```
import gettext
gettext.install('test', "./locale")
_ = gettext.gettext

t = gettext.translation('test', "./locale", languages=['fr'])
t.install()

print _("Hello world")
```

./locale/fr/LC_messages/test.mo contains the translation (as binary file, generated by running msgfmt on a .po file).

Program prints "Hello world" instead of the translated version. What could be the problem?

Comment: a stab in the dark, maybe it's case sensitive?

Comment: capitalisation difference was a typo here not present in the actual program - I'll edit the question to fix that

Comment: Why are you using `.install()` (twice) *and* binding `_`?

Comment: ah that was it - binding _() was the problem. Remove that and it works.

Comment: Answer and close if it's resolved, guys...

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this answer is WAY too late, but I just found this and I think it can help you.

```
import gettext

t = gettext.translation('test', "./locale", languages=['fr'])
_ = t.gettext

print _("Hello world")
```

In my own programm, I did it this way:

```
import gettext

DIR = "lang"
APP = "ToolName"
gettext.textdomain(APP)
gettext.bindtextdomain(APP, DIR)
#gettext.bind_textdomain_codeset("default", 'UTF-8') # Not necessary
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "")
LANG = "FR_fr"


lang = gettext.translation(APP, DIR, languages=[LANG], fallback = True)
_ = lang.gettext
```

**NOTE**:

My program has a *lang* directory on it.
For every language a directory is made in *lang* : *XX_xx* (`en_US`)
Inside the directory `en_US` there is `LC_MESSAGES`, and inside there is `TOOLNAME.mo`

But that's my way for cross-language.